# Passing/Initializing Parameter from Last Build in TeamCity Build Chain

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, pipeline

I just started with the TeamCity CI server. I have 2 builds

- API-Tests
- UI-Tests

Both these builds run in parallel whereas both the builds will have a dropdown config parameter with choices(Regression, Sanity)

I have a build name **Release** with a similar dropdown config parameter with choices(Regression, Sanity) and this build depends on both **API-Tests** and **UI-Tests**. The build **Release** will have to trigger manually by choosing the dropdown parameter(Regression, Sanity).

I want to pass the option chosen in the **Release** build to both **API-Tests** and **UI-Tests** builds. I can't use %dep.*%, since **Release** build depends on **API-Tests** and **UI-Tests** builds.

I have attached the build chain for reference. Please guide me to fix the requirement or suggest at least a workaround.

[Sample Build Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgOUq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the `reverse.dep.*` pattern, which is best described in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#Overriding+Dependencies+Properties).

Quoting the docs:

> It is possible to redefine build parameters in the snapshot-dependency builds when the current build starts. For example, build configuration A depends on B and B depends on C; on triggering, A can change any parameter used in B or C.

It looks like this is your case:

> To change a parameter in all dependencies at once, use a wildcard:
> `reverse.dep.*.<property_name>`

Anyway, I would encourage you to read the whole article to get thorough understanding of the subject and choose the most suitable option.

Comment: Thank you Yan. It worked.